# Foreman export upstart scripts as userjob on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, foreman, upstart

I am trying to export upstart scripts from my rails application using foreman but I don't want to use sudo to do that. 
I saw that the Ubuntu 12.04 that I am using supports userjob http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#user-job so I have enabled that. It was enabled successfully with a test script that I have placed at `~/.init` so I tried `bundle exec foreman export upstart ~/.init -a myapp -l log -u myuser` and it exported all my foreman tasks to ~/.init.
Now when I run `start myapp` it works however my thin instances simply doesn't start and I can't figure out why. Maybe it has something to do with using a RVM user install. Is there a way to debug this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set

`console log`

in your upstart script, and the output should be shown in a log-fie.

According to the [recen upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#console-log), session job output will appear in `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/upstart/<jobname>`, (which [should](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) fall back to `$HOME/.cache`).

Alternatively, you can tell it to log elsewhere, with the `--logdir` option to the upstart command.

Since your question is a few months old, you may already be aware that using `$HOME/.init` for "user" jobs is deprecated in favour of `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/upstart` (or `$HOME/.config/upstart/`). Looks like the [latest Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/tree/v0.63.0) doesn't give nice defaults for that, though it's still possible.

As for the reason your script won't start, some things to consider are

- Are you running as the right user? `setuid <user>`
- Does that user have access to `bundle` in this environment?

I'm not sure about RVM, but I've had some success with [chruby](http://github.com/postmodern/chruby). Here's an example (which logs):

```
description "A Rails application" 
author "Me (me@example.com)"

start on runlevel [2345] 
stop on runlevel [016] 

respawn 

setuid appuser 
setgid appuser 

console output 

chdir /var/www/app/current 
exec chruby-exec 2.0 -- bundle exec unicorn_rails -E production -P 5000
```